# A couple of questions on ordinal numbers

Tags: set-theory

While going over von Neumann's definition of ordinal number I made a couple of conjectures whose veracity I have not been to able to decide yet. I share them here in order to pick up hints (counterexamples?) for settling them.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals and $h$ an injective function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

**c**-1. The direct image of $\alpha$ under $h$, $h(\alpha)$, is also an ordinal number.

*Proof attempt.* All we need to establish is the transitivity of $h(\alpha)$. Let $x \in h(\alpha)$. It follows that $x= h(\gamma)$ for some ordinal number $\gamma \in \alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is an ordinal number, it follows that $\gamma \subseteq \alpha$. Then $\gamma=\{y \in \alpha: y\in \gamma\}$; hence

$$h(\gamma) = h(\{y \in \alpha: y\in \gamma\}) = \{z \in \beta: z = h(y) \text{ for some } y \in \gamma\} \subseteq h(\alpha)$$

and we can conclude that $x \subseteq \alpha$ (can't we?).

**c**-2. Any injective function between ordinal numbers induces an order-preserving injective function between them.

*Proof attempt.* Fix two ordinal numbers, say $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and let $h$ be an injective function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Besides, let us denote with $B$ the direct image of $\alpha$ under $h$. I believe that we can create a function from $\alpha \to \beta$ if we proceed thus: take the minimal element $\alpha_{0}$ of $\alpha$ and map it to the minimal element of $B$, the second minimal element of $\alpha$ (or in other words, the minimal element of $\alpha \setminus \{\alpha_{0}\}$) goes to the second minimal element of $B$, and so on. Methinks that this gives eventually an order-preserving injection $F$ from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. What do you guys think? Can such a handwaving argument be made totally rigorous?

Finally, it is to be noted that **c**-2 doesn't presuppose **c**-1!

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Conjecture $1$ is obviously false. Suppose $\alpha=1$, $\beta=20$, and $h(0)=3$. The direct image of $\alpha$ under $h$ is $\{3\}$, not an ordinal.

Comment: I am not sure I understand conjecture 2. What do you mean by "induces"? It is surely false under a naive interpretation. Say $\alpha=\omega+\omega$, $\beta=\omega$. There is an injective function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ but there are no order preserving injections from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ (whether they are "induced" or not).

Comment: And wherein did the sketched proof of c-1 go wrong?

Comment: That's something you should be be able to figure out on your own.

Comment: Paradoxical, right?

Comment: You had a mismatch in font sizes because you used \mbox{} instead of \text{}.  I fixed it.

Comment: The proof in c-1 is incomplete. The problematic bit is that you only show $x \in h(\alpha) -> x \subset h(\alpha)$. You need both directions, and the other one is the one that fails, as can be seen from Andres counterexample above.